# pyplot axes lines are too thin

Tags: matplotlib, line, axes

I try this after some hours:

```
plt.plot_date(dados_ana['Data'],dados_ana['NumDiasDeChuva'], xdate=True, 
markersize=30)
plt.title('Numero de dias com Chuva')
plt.grid(color='r', linestyle='-', linewidth=4)
#plt.axhline(linewidth=4, color="g")     
#plt.axvline(linewidth=4, color="r")       
#plt.axes(linewidth=4)
```

The above # part dont work.

I got this:

[image: this is the link to the image because I am not alowed yet to put images]

But you can see in the link the lines of the axes are to thin.
Is a "plt.something" that I can change this problem?

I also tried the "linewidth=4" after the markersize and dont work.

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to change the linewidth of the **spines**.

```
for _, spine in plt.gca().spines.items():
    spine.set_linewidth(4)
```

Comment: Great! I just copy and paste to my Jupyter Notebook this code and works!! The axes lines are visible now! thanks a lot!

Comment: Additional help. I follow the same code to change the color line:    for _, spine in plt.gca().spines.items():
    spine.set_color(k)

Comment: Get this: NameError: name 'k' is not defined

Comment: Well, you would need to define `k` first, as the error suggests. E.g. `k="red"`.

Comment: Thanks, again! It works. I put k='black'. The first time I used "k" because in a Google search return matplotlib understand k = black.